# How to Auto Increment Part of Varchar

Tags: mysql

I trying to create a query to auto increment a Varchar column. The number values is a date value, highlighted, are the numbers I'm trying to increment by 7. Is there a way to auto increment the number/date value within the number column?

**From**

```
select * from table_name where number = 'ABC**070516**A001'
```

**To**

```
select * from table_name where number = 'ABC**071216**A001'
```

Comment: did my suggestion work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you have the option to do it outside of MySql - do it.**

If you know exactly the format of your numbers - `3 letters + date + something else` you can do this:

```
REPLACE('ABC070516A001', MID('ABC070516A001', 4, 6), DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE(MID('ABC070516A001', 4, 6), '%m%d%y'), INTERVAL 7 DAY), '%m%d%y'))
```

It will do the following:

1. Extract the date number - `MID('ABC070516A001', 4, 6)` This suggests that it always has 3 letters in the beginning. If the format is more complex you will need a library with regex replace function
2. Converts the extracted number to Date object `STR_TO_DATE('070516', '%m%d%y')`
3. Adds interval of 7 days to the date object. This will handle all the cases like transition to new month and new year. `DATE_ADD('2016-07-05', INTERVAL 7 DAY)`
4. Formats the result date to your number format `DATE_FORMAT('2016-07-12', '%m%d%y')`
5. Replaces the number with the new number `REPLACE('ABC070516A001', MID('ABC070516A001', 4, 6), '071216')`

Answer (score 1):

Well, in your queries you are not incrementing anything. You are making two selects. If you wanted to change the value of a varchar column to be auto increment it's not possible. At least not with out lot's and lot's of code.

The simplest solution for you is to create three separate columns and to make the third one auto increment.

```
col1     col2    col3
ABC      070516  A001
ABC      071216  A001
```

Then concatenate the columns at the time of retrieval/display.